# Get all url from a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
[
{
"profilechecksum":"58cd944da7b8e647abdcdb722d74fc7ai9060852",
"userloginstatus":"Last Online today",
"subscription_text":null,
"subscription_icon":null,
"age":"22 Years",
"username":"ZZXS8433",
"height":"5' 2\" ",
"occupation":"Not working",
"caste":"Namasudra\/Namosudra",
"income":"No Income",
"mtongue":"Bengali",
"edu_level_new":"High School",
"location":"Kolkata",
"photo":{
"label":null,
"url":"http:\/\/mediacdn.jeevansathi.com\/866\/17\/17337654-1375139585.jpeg",
"action":null
},
"size":null,
"album_count":"1",
"timetext":null,
"seen":"Y",
"religion":"Hindu",
"gender":"F",
"featured":null,
"filter_score":"",
"filter_reason":"",
"highlighted":0,
"verification_seal":null,
"verification_status":null,
"mstatus":"Never Married",
"college":null,
"pg_college":null,
"company_name":null,
"gunascore":null,
"name_of_user":null,
"profileid":"9060852",
"buttonDetails":{
"buttons":[
{
"iconid":"001",
"label":"Send Interest",
"action":"INITIATE",
"value":null,
"params":null
},
{
"iconid":"003",
"label":"Shortlist",
"action":"SHORTLIST",
"value":null,
"params":"&shortlist=false"
},
{
"iconid":"005",
"label":"Photo",
"action":"ALBUM",
"value":"1",
"params":null
},
{
"iconid":"007",
"label":"Contact",
"action":"CONTACTDETAIL",
"value":null,
"params":null
}
],
"button":null,
"infomsgiconid":null,
"infomsglabel":null,
"infobtnlabel":null,
"infobtnvalue":null,
"infobtnaction":null
},
"buttonDetailsJSMS":{
"buttons":[
{
"action":"INITIATE",
"label":"Send Interest",
"iconid":null,
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"params":"&stype=A",
"enable":true,
"id":"INITIATE"
},
{
"iconid":null,
"label":"View Contacts",
"action":"CONTACT_DETAIL",
"value":null,
"params":null,
"enable":true,
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"id":"CONTACT_DETAIL"
},
{
"action":"CHAT",
"label":"Chat",
"iconid":null,
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"enable":true,
"id":"CHAT",
"params":"ZZXS8433,9060852,http:\/\/mediacdn.jeevansathi.com\/866\/17\/17337654-1375139585.jpeg,N"
},
{
"action":"SHORTLIST",
"iconid":"003",
"label":"Shortlist",
"params":"&shortlist=false",
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"enable":"true",
"id":"SHORTLIST"
}
],
"button":null,
"infomsgiconid":null,
"infomsglabel":null,
"infobtnlabel":null,
"infobtnvalue":null,
"infobtnaction":null
}
},
{
"profilechecksum":"3c08e787ae61cbfada3232eb5393fa2fi8295748",
"userloginstatus":"Last Online today",
"subscription_text":null,
"subscription_icon":null,
"age":"22 Years",
"username":"ZAUY2793",
"height":"5' 2\" ",
"occupation":"Student",
"caste":"Jhijhotiya",
"income":"No Income",
"mtongue":"Hindi-MP",
"edu_level_new":"B.Com",
"location":"Indore",
"photo":{
"label":null,
"url":"http:\/\/mediacdn.jeevansathi.com\/713\/7\/14267803-1374952962.jpeg",
"action":null
},
"size":null,
"album_count":"2",
"timetext":null,
"seen":"Y",
"religion":"Hindu",
"gender":"F",
"featured":null,
"filter_score":"",
"filter_reason":"",
"highlighted":0,
"verification_seal":null,
"verification_status":null,
"mstatus":"Never Married",
"college":null,
"pg_college":null,
"company_name":null,
"gunascore":null,
"name_of_user":null,
"profileid":"8295748",
"buttonDetails":{
"buttons":[
{
"iconid":"001",
"label":"Send Interest",
"action":"INITIATE",
"value":null,
"params":null
},
{
"iconid":"003",
"label":"Shortlist",
"action":"SHORTLIST",
"value":null,
"params":"&shortlist=false"
},
{
"iconid":"005",
"label":"Album",
"action":"ALBUM",
"value":"2",
"params":null
},
{
"iconid":"007",
"label":"Contact",
"action":"CONTACTDETAIL",
"value":null,
"params":null
}
],
"button":null,
"infomsgiconid":null,
"infomsglabel":null,
"infobtnlabel":null,
"infobtnvalue":null,
"infobtnaction":null
},
"buttonDetailsJSMS":{
"buttons":[
{
"action":"INITIATE",
"label":"Send Interest",
"iconid":null,
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"params":"&stype=A",
"enable":true,
"id":"INITIATE"
},
{
"iconid":null,
"label":"View Contacts",
"action":"CONTACT_DETAIL",
"value":null,
"params":null,
"enable":true,
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"id":"CONTACT_DETAIL"
},
{
"action":"CHAT",
"label":"Chat",
"iconid":null,
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"enable":true,
"id":"CHAT",
"params":"ZAUY2793,8295748,http:\/\/mediacdn.jeevansathi.com\/713\/7\/14267803-1374952962.jpeg,N"
},
{
"action":"SHORTLIST",
"iconid":"003",
"label":"Shortlist",
"params":"&shortlist=false",
"primary":"true",
"secondary":null,
"enable":"true",
"id":"SHORTLIST"
}
],
"button":null,
"infomsgiconid":null,
"infomsglabel":null,
"infobtnlabel":null,
"infobtnvalue":null,
"infobtnaction":null
}
}
]
```

I want to write a regex to get `"url":"http:\/\/mediacdn.jeevansathi.com\/866\/17\/17337654-1375139585.jpeg"` from it(i.e., only url part).

I tried :

```
 p = re.compile("\"url\":\".*\.jpeg\"") # parentheses for capture groups
            print p.findall(line) #
```

But it's not giving me only url section.

Comment: Add a capturing group - `re.compile(r'"url":"(.*\.jpeg)"')`

Comment: Not working. https://regex101.com/r/4MvHDj/1

Comment: *You are using `re.findall`*, not regex101, *in your **code***.

Answer (score 1):

Regex seems like the wrong tool here. This is a JSON string; you should parse it then search for items where the `url` attribute ends with `jpeg`.

```
data = json.loads(my_string)
results = [item['photo']['url'] for item in results if item.get('photo', '{}').get('url', '').endswith('jpeg')]
```

Comment: I want to use regex for the same because, my string is not pure json. It can have starting and ending prefixes too.